# Startx from SSH terminal

Tags: electron

I am trying to see console messages of an Electron app on a Raspberry Pi display. If I type `startx` from the Pi using the keyboard, the app starts up but I can't see the console messages since the Electron app is on the display. How do I `startx` from an SSH connection, have the app show on the PI display but the console messages display on the SSH terminal? If not possible, how do I pipe the console messages to a file I can view after I quit the Electron app?

Comment: See use of `&` https://askubuntu.com/questions/574728/execute-command-in-terminal-an-dont-wait-its-return for patching application to same terminal without waiting.  You can also redirect to whatever files and streams you wish.

Answer (score 0):

"How do I startx from an SSH connection" - you don't.

If you want a GUI you need to start it on boot.

It IS possible to start a virtual VNC session over ssh.

It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. If your application does not write to stdout you won't get any output.

Maybe try running on VNC.